# Поднять веб-сервер дома

Tags: mamp, denwer, веб-сервер

Всем привет и у меня такой вопрос, как запустить веб-сервер так, чтобы он работал? Т.е. у меня есть ip 91.79.74.4,  и как сделать так, чтобы вы могли на него зайти и у вас появился сайт, как, например, 93.186.224.240.

Что я имею:

1. у меня есть макбук и замечательная программа MAMP (аналог denwer), для того что бы запустить сервер (192.168.1.2)
2. роутер zte (192.168.1.1)

Когда я вбиваю свой ip (91.79.74.4), у меня появляется аутентификация моего модема, а я хочу, что бы появлялся мой веб-сайт.

Comment: а Apache для чего? Юзайте вирт хостинг

Answer (score 2):

С вашим роутером не работал, но в самом простейшем случае вы должны сделать следующее:

1. Чтобы не указывать особый порт каждый раз при входе на ваш сайт, вам необходимо сменить в настройках порт по-умолчанию для админки на роутере (модеме). Например, сделать его не 80, а 8080. Правда, тогда вам при входе в админку придется каждый раз писать не просто http://192.168.1.1, а http://192.168.1.1:8080 т.к. порт не стандартный для протокола http.
2. После этого вы настраиваете "проброс портов" (port forwarding), где в качестве входящего и исходящего порта ставите 80, протокол - `tcp` и ваш IP (192.168.1.2)

После этого все запросы протокола `tcp` на порт 80 ваш роутер будет пересылать на ваш же компьютер.

Answer (score 2):

Также можно добавить к сказанному!

1. Зарегить какой-нибудь домен (example.ru)
2. Зарегиться на wreedns.ws, получить записи DNS сервера (IP поставить  91.79.74.4), прописать их для домена.

И при заходe на example.ru - будете заходить к себе на ноут.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так не стал бы делать...
На буке:
 1. настраиваем Вашу замечательную програмку слушать 80-й порт на localhost (127.0.0.1);
 2. тестим странички на сервере до тех пор пока не настроим как надо (в браузере забиваем этот адрес и смотрим странички);
 3. после этого перенастраиваем вэб-сервер на то, чтоб слушал 8080-й порт на Вашем локальном адресе бука (предположим это 192.168.1.2)
На рутере:
 1. читаем манку рутера, и в соответсвии с ней настраиваем проброс портов: с внешнего адреса 91.79.74.4 порт 80 на 192.168.1.2 порт 8080;
 2. если в рутере имеется функция указания серверов, прописываем 192.168.1.2 в туда

Даем адресочек (внешний) друзьям и просим потестить. Если есть желание работать с доменными именами (ну чтоб Вас искали по имени: вася_пупкин) то настраиваем DDNS - во многих рутерах есть данная опция (предварительно зарегиться на DDNS).

Comment: А какой практический смысл по вашему мнению по отношению к моему варианту?

Comment: 1. Не нужно перенастраивать web-конфигуратор рутера (тем более, что не все рутеры дают такую возможность);2. как вы собираетесь создать петлю вн_сеть > рутер  > внеш_адрес_рутера > вн_сеть? - тут не выйдет простой проброс портов.

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве современных рутеров есть фича не "проброса", а "переадресации" портов. То есть - отображение одного и того же порта на другой (внутренний) адрес. В принципе, это тот же "проброс", только порт не меняется, а меняется лишь адрес.

Но если это порт 80 (HTTP), то вы лишаетесь веб-доступа к самому роутеру. Палка - она о двух концах!

Comment: Никто веб-доступа не лишается. Просто не нужно ходить на сайт по внешнему адресу, потому что этот адрес принадлежит маршрутизатору. Нужно ходить на 127.0.0.1, тогда никаких проблем с попаданием в админку не будет.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это localhost, то есть внутренний адрес не роутера, а собственно компьютера. Поэтому туда ходить бесполезно!

Comment: если веб-сервер настроен на локалхост, то ходить следует именно на локалхост!

Comment: Вопрос от автора прочитай внимательно. Ему не от локалхоста надо, а извне!